# How to display optional data in GridView yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have field "status" in my table,where the field value is 1 or 2.
I want display GridView yii2 if 1 then active and if 2 then not active

Comment: Could you please clarify your question, and write what you already tried?

Comment: I want to display optional data in gridview yii2. if value data is 1 then display "Active".

Answer (score 1):

```
[   
        'format' => 'html',
        'attribute' => 'field_name',
        'value' => function($data) {
            return ($data->field_name == 1 ? 'active' : 'not active');
        },
    ],
```

You may try this code